# Can a POST value ever be an instanceof something in PHP?

Tags: php, object, comparison, instanceof

I've come across PHP code with the a check which tests if a POST value is an `instanceof` a class:

```
if ($_POST['something'] instanceof SomeClass) {
    // do something
}
```

This seems odd to me, because I wouldn't think that the check can ever be true. A POST value is a string after all, and a string isn't an instance of a class.

I tried passing the serialized version of an instance (`O:9:"SomeClass":0:{}`), but that doesn't work (which makes sense, as it's still a string, not an object).

Am I correct in thinking that this check can never be true? Or am I missing something here?

Comment: Yeah it looks like nonsense to me

Comment: Let’s hope there’s no preprocessing of the `$_POST` array going on anywhere…‽

Comment: @deceze not as far as I could see (I'm doing a security audit of the code, so that would have been ... interesting).

Answer (score 0):

I think this is not a simple question. I think theoretically "yes".

As a $_POST is a array of variables, and there is no limitation what the elements of a array can be, you can for example create a array of objects.

```
$array[] = new stdClass;
$array[0]->variable = value;
etc ...
```

You see the code author is checking if $_POST['something'], that is a element of the array, and that easily can be a object, is a instance of a class.

Now I have not tested it, but theoretically one could put a object of a class in a array and send it via $_POST nicely encoded.

Comment: Yes but php would decode it into an array, not a class

Comment: The only thing that could make the OP's code necessary is if some code which receives the request has interfered with the $_POST array directly before this point in the script

Comment: @ADyson just to tease you a little :  `$object = (object) $array;` or `$object = json_decode(json_encode($array), FALSE);`  ;-)

Comment: thanks for your answer! But for the purpose of this question, `$_POST` is the default `$_POST` variable as populated by PHP; it is not manipulated in any way on the server via custom PHP code. Of course if we assume manipulation, it's trivially possible to pass the check (eg `$_POST['something'] = unserialize($_POST['something'])`).

Comment: @MaxMuster yeah but we're talking about the automated decoding of data from the http request into $_POST which php does by default, not some custom code.